# Angular compilation warning: "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, npm, package, mqtt

I'm trying to serve an Angular application, but i'm getting this dependency error from "ngx-mqtt": "^6.6.0". My local CLI is 6.2.9 version. I'm trying to change versions of this dependency, but i'm still getting this error. I just can't figure out why this is happening.

> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-mqtt/src/mqtt.service.js 390:34-55 
>   "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-mqtt/src/mqtt.service.js 390:126-137
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-mqtt/src/mqtt.service.js 390:161-172
>   "export 'ɵɵinject' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'

these are my main dependencies from package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.2.1",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
...
```

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
        "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
        "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
        "tslint": "^5.11.0",
        "typescript": "^2.9.2"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the character `^` from `"ngx-mqtt": "^6.6.0"` resolved the problem.

Comment: In my case, my Angular version was 11.0.5 and some of the packages were `^11.0.5` so I removed the `^` character and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Current project angular version
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node:14.17.2

1. Delete nodemodule folder
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. Edit package

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod -c code-qa",
    "ssl": "ng serve --port 4400 --ssl true --ssl-cert ../ssl/server.crt --ssl-key ../ssl/server.key",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.24",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@egjs/view360": "^3.2.2-rc",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.1.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.1.1",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.4",
    "angular-progress-bar": "^1.0.9",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "find-remove": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "marzipano": "^0.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-intercom": "^8.0.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.9",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.10.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "2.0.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-rangeslider-component": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

4. after saving all the changed files
   run npm i --legacy-peer-deps

5.run npm start

6.if you are getting the below-mentioned warning

WARNING in ./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js
4538:120-128 "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
WARNING in ./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js
4538:34-52 "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.

7. go to path ./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js  and open agm-core.js file and search "ɵɵinject"  then remove "ee" and keep it as "inject"
   the search "ɵɵdefineInjectable" remove "ee" and keep it as "defineInjectable"

8.save this changed file

9. run again npm start
10. It will work

Thank you all